# ERROR: KeeperErrorCode comes when create table in hbase in Standalone HBase

Tags: ubuntu, hbase

this error comes when trying to create a new table on Hbase Standalone way.

```
hbase:002:0> create 'test', 'cf'

ERROR: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/master
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can miss the command of running the HBase master. you should run the Hbase master node using this code

```
[your Hbase path]/bin/start-hbase.sh
```

and then you cane see the dashboard of the `master-status` on port `16010` like below.

```
http://localhost:16010/
```

read more on [official documentation](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#quickstart).